# Keep getting error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol

Tags: c++, linker, icu, unresolved-external

The IDE I use is Visual Studio 2010 Professional, and the library I use is [ICU](http://site.icu-project.org/)4C 4.8.1 for Win32 for MSVC10.

I have rebuilt all the source codes according to the manual for both Debug and Release, and all tests are successfully passed.

Then I do in the way I do with Boost.

I included *\include* in *C/C++ > Additional Include Directories* in *Proprieties*, which seems to be fine.

I also included *\lib* in *Linker > Additional Library Directories*.

However, I keep getting `error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol`.

Source Code:

```
#include <unicode/uchar.h>

int main () {
    UBool b = u_isprint('c');
    return 0;
}
```

Error

```
1>ClCompile:
1>  Main.cpp
1>Main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _u_isprint_48 referenced in function _main
1>C:\Users\ ... \Documents\Visual Studio\Finger-Printing-Non-ASCII\Debug\Finger-Printing-Non-ASCII.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals
1>
1>Build FAILED.
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Apart from setting additional include directories and library directories, you have to actually *link* to the library. Go to Project Properties -> Linker -> Input and write the name to the .lib in *Additional dependencies* textbox. HTH

Comment: Thank you. I am sorry but _there_ is where?

Comment: @Schnommus Type all the .lib's names in?

Comment: @Dante is not a Geek Yes; but only the actual lib's <name>.lib - The directory that the lib is actually **located** in you stick in VC++ directories->library directories